# Is there an edge such that increasing it's capacity would increase the max-flow?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

> Let $G\langle V,E\rangle$, a flow-network. I need to check if there's an edge such that increasing it's capacity would increase the max flow of the graph.

There's such an edge, if there's a path, $p$, from $s$ to $t$ such that there's *exactly one* saturated edge in $p$.

So the problem is reduced to checking if such a path exists.

I think I could utilize BFS algorithm for that cause. Basically I could tag each scanned vertex "If we reached it by a path contains a saturated edge" and each vertex could get into queue more than one time.

I'm having troubles with formalizing it into a proof.

Is that a good approach? Can you help me with proving/formalizing it?

Thanks.

Comment: This is closely related (a special case) of [Find the minimum amount of edges in a graph to improve flow](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882423/find-the-minimum-amount-of-edges-in-a-graph-to-improve-flow).  My answer frames the check as a shortest-path-finding problem, but your desire to formalize a proof arguably makes for a distinct Question.

Comment: If you are interested in having a distinct Question about "proving/formalizing it", may I suggest that you formulate the specific statement to be proved?  At present your Question focuses on "I need to check...", and the proposal to "tag each scanned vertex" is not (to me) a clear proposition capable of proof.